# Integrated Camera not working

Tags: drivers, asus, camera, ubuntu-drivers

My integrated camera on my Asus Laptop is not working. When I open an application like Cheese, it shows "no device found".

Integrated Camera: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam

Output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:6205 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. C-Media(R) Audio
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 322e:202c Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c062 Logitech, Inc. M-UAS144 [LS1 Laser Mouse]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The dmesg output confirms that my Sonix Technology USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam is detected by the system. The uvcvideo driver is also loaded, which is responsible for handling UVC-compatible webcams. However, there is a warning about UVC non-compliance:

```
[    2.085360] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=322e, idProduct=202c, bcdDevice= 1.03
[    2.085377] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.085382] usb 1-7: Product: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
[    2.085387] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
[    4.663589] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    4.663031] usb 1-7: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
```

Full Output of dmesg | grep -i usb:

```
[    0.013268] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000040B86000 000ECF (v02 _ASUS_ UsbCTabl 00001000 INTL 20200717)
[    0.207662] ACPI: USB4 _OSC: OS supports USB3+ DisplayPort+ PCIe+ XDomain+
[    0.207664] ACPI: USB4 _OSC: OS controls USB3+ DisplayPort+ PCIe+ XDomain+
[    0.742510] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.742510] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.742510] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.742510] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.322223] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.323501] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.323503] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[    1.323526] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.05
[    1.323527] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.323528] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.323529] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 6.5.0-26-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.323530] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.323689] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.324909] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.05
[    1.324911] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.324912] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.324912] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 6.5.0-26-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.324913] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.324993] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.491205] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.492375] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    1.492376] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0d.0: Host supports USB 3.2 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[    1.492782] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.05
[    1.492784] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.492785] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.492786] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 6.5.0-26-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.492787] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:0d.0
[    1.492999] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.493338] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.05
[    1.493340] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.493341] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.493341] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 6.5.0-26-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.493342] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:0d.0
[    1.493404] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.579698] usb 1-2: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.733840] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c062, bcdDevice=31.00
[    1.733846] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.733847] usb 1-2: Product: USB Laser Mouse
[    1.733849] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    1.863760] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.085360] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=322e, idProduct=202c, bcdDevice= 1.03
[    2.085377] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.085382] usb 1-7: Product: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
[    2.085387] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
[    2.219642] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    3.355911] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=0b05, idProduct=6205, bcdDevice= 1.06
[    3.355930] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.355935] usb 1-9: Product: C-Media(R) Audio
[    3.355940] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
[    3.487633] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    3.640474] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0026, bcdDevice= 0.02
[    3.640497] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.683795] input: Logitech USB Laser Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:046D:C062.0003/input/input7
[    3.683932] hid-generic 0003:046D:C062.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Laser Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[    3.687407] input: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. C-Media(R) Audio as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.3/0003:0B05:6205.0004/input/input8
[    3.748655] hid-generic 0003:0B05:6205.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. C-Media(R) Audio] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9/input3
[    3.748795] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    3.748802] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    4.648479] usb 1-7: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam (322e:202c)
[    4.649325] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    4.663031] usb 1-7: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
[    4.663589] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    4.731131] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[    6.527557] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: error -ETIMEDOUT: PPM init failed
```

How can I troubleshoot this issue further?
Are there any additional drivers or configurations required to make the camera work?
What does the "UVC non-compliance" warning mean, and how can I address it?

Thanks for your answers and suggestions

Comment: Add yourself to the `video` group with `sudo adduser $USER video`, then logout and login (groups are set up at login time).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but did not work for me. Any other ideas?